# How can ligature information be exported from a TrueType font?

Tags: fonts, truetype

How can ligature information be exported from a TrueType font file? In OpenType, there is the `GSUB` table that contains the necessary information.

Is there a TrueType equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TrueType fonts don't have anything akin to GSUB. cmap table selects exactly one glyph only for given character, no additional context is given. I guess you already looked [here](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cmap.htm)...

Comment: I did. I had to abandon this project for a while, but will get to it soon again. Thanks!